# formula for winning a best of n series?

Tags: probability

is there a formula to calculate the probability of winning a best of n series, given that the probability of winning each individual game is p?

Answer (score 1):

In a best of $n$ series, we can have up to $2n - 1$ games.
We can form an equivalent problem by having a set of $2n-1$ games and declaring the person who wins at least $n$ games as the winner.
Then the distribution of the number of games that this person has won is $\operatorname{Binomial}(2n-1, p)$, and the probability that this random variable is at least $n$ is
$$\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1}p^i(1-p)^{2n-1-i}\binom{2n-1}{i}.$$

Comment: A best-of-7 series like the NBA Finals cannot have $(2\times 7)-1=13$ games.

Comment: @Dave You mistake a tournament among $2^n$ teams for a series of games between $2$ teams.

Comment: @whuber How so? A best-of-seven series means seven games if necessary but first to four wins.

Comment: @Dave I see: I misinterpreted "NBA finals" as "NBA playoffs."  I agree with your use of "best-of-seven," which differs from how Anon interprets it here.  But because the present answer clearly indicates how "best of $n$" is being interpreted, and because this interpretation answers the question, I find it clear and correct.  One might ordinarily characterize this as "first to $n$ wins" or "best of $2n-1.$"